# updating value in html table via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi is there any way to upadte cell value with no events (i dont want to use 'onClick' or others)?

The scheme is: user is filling form value, then clicks 'ok', and then value should be showed in cell in html table ?

thx in advance for all help

Comment: Without events ... How will your code know when the 'ok' button is clicked?

Comment: i mean no events in table like: <table id="xxx" onClick="myFunc()">

Comment: Please try to be more clear. Do you want no events at all? Or just not on the table? In that last case you can just use a button in the `<form>` where you have the input field and add the onclick event to that button..

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use a link with `href="javascript:myFunction()"` instead of an onclick, but I'm not sure if that counts as an event :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to hook up on an even to trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the user is going to click the Ok link anyways that seems to be the most relevant place to invoke your javascript from.

1. Create a div with an id around the content you would like to change.
2. Create a javascript function that sets the innerHTML of the above div.
3. Call the javascript function when the user hits the Ok link.